# PHP Session expires after changing page

Tags: php, session

Hi i have 2 simple pages for test sessions in php

first page :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['hello'] = 'world';
?>
```

second page:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
?>
```

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/itmediaquality/public_html/testsession2.php on line 5

Comment: Now if you started your session, but you got the warning about the header already being sent: Google -> `php header already sent` first link

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `session_start()` on the second page.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
?>
```